# Swift protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols

Very much appreciated the [article](https://medium.com/swift-programming/uistoryboard-safer-with-enums-protocol-extensions-and-generics-7aad3883b44d#.3nov922n4) about getting rid of using strings when instantiating `UIViewController` or `UIStoryboard`.

Though there is one point where I wanted to change the behavior.
Instead of giving a Storyboard enum into the class method for getting a storyboard, I wanted a type here that conforms to a protocol.

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    class func storyboard(storyboard: StoryboardRepresentable, bundle: NSBundle? = nil) -> UIStoryboard {
         return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.storyboardName, bundle: bundle)
    }
}

protocol StringRawRepresentable: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = String
    var rawValue: String { get }
}

protocol StoryboardRepresentable {
    var storyboardName: String { get }
}

extension StoryboardRepresentable where Self: StringRawRepresentable {
    var storyboardName: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

enum SomeOtherEnum: String, StoryboardRepresentable {
    case BlaMain
    case BlaSub
    case BlaSomeThing

    var storyboardName: String { return self.rawValue }
}
```

With that (given you have several moduls interesting in using this implementation) the models themselves could have new enum types conforming to StoryboardRepresentable instead of having a centralized enum with knowledge about all storyboards in use and thus creating a dependency.

And here is my problem. Though I have implemented the storyboardName in the extension, I got a compiler error complaining about non-protocol conformance when I remove the storyboardName on SomeOtherEnum!?

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UIStoryboard {
    class func storyboard(storyboard: StoryboardRepresentable, bundle: NSBundle? = nil) -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.storyboardName, bundle: bundle)
    }
}

protocol StoryboardRepresentable {
    var storyboardName: String { get }
}

extension StoryboardRepresentable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var storyboardName: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

enum SomeOtherEnum: String, StoryboardRepresentable {
    case BlaMain
    case BlaSub
    case BlaSomeThing
}
```

`StoryboardRepresentable` can now be applied to any enum of type `String` but not to type `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

`StringRawRepresentable` is not directly related to `StoryboardRepresentable`.
Since the protocol extension affects only `StoryboardRepresentable`objects which also conform to `StringRawRepresentable` you have to declare `SomeOtherEnum`

```
enum SomeOtherEnum: String, StoryboardRepresentable, StringRawRepresentable {
```

Comment: How can I accomplish that the StoryboardRepresentable is only valid on types that conform to StringRawRepresentable?

Comment: In this combination it's not possible because `StringRawRepresentable` can't be used as a type due to the `Self` requirement. Adding both protocol conformances is a pretty good design I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Finally you've lead me into the right direction. Though I can't understand why SomeOtherEnum does not comply to StringRawRepresentable, as it rawValue returns a String, modifiying the code did the trick. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage Storyboards and ViewController instantiation with help of several protocols/extensions.

UIStoryboardInstantiatable is a wrapper for generic instantiation methods:

```
public protocol UIStoryboardInstantiatable {
    func instantiate<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T?
    func instantiateInitial<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T?
    func instantiateInitial() -> UIViewController?
}

public extension UIStoryboardInstantiatable {
    func instantiateInitial() -> UIViewController? {
        return instantiateInitial(controller: UIViewController.self)
    }
}

public extension UIStoryboardInstantiatable where Self: UIStoryboardRepresentable {
    func instantiate<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T? {
        return storyboard.instantiate(controller: T.self)
    }

    func instantiateInitial<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T? {
        return storyboard.instantiateInitial(controller: T.self)
    }
}

public extension UIStoryboardInstantiatable where Self: UIStoryboard {
    func instantiate<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T? {
        return instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: T.className) as? T
    }

    func instantiateInitial<T: UIViewController>(controller: T.Type) -> T? {
        return instantiateInitialViewController() as? T
    }
}
```

In the future all our storyboards will be UIStoryboardRepresentables.

```
public protocol UIStoryboardRepresentable: UIStoryboardInstantiatable {
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard { get }
    var bundle: Bundle { get }
}

public extension UIStoryboardRepresentable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var storyboard: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard.init(name: rawValue, bundle: bundle)
    }
}
```

Now you can create list of storyboards presented in your application:

```
public enum AppStoryboard: String, UIStoryboardRepresentable {
    case components
    case main
    case news

    public var bundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle.main
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        return "\(self)".capitalizingFirstLetter()
    }
}
```

Small String extension for capitalizing first letter of rawValue. Because by convention Storyboard names are pascal case and the enum cases are camel case.

```
extension String {
    public func capitalizingFirstLetter() -> String {
        return prefix(1).uppercased() + dropFirst()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let controller = AppStoryboard.main.instantiate(controller: TestViewController.self)
```

From project to project only AppStoryboard is changing.