# How to use generic function with current type Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a protocol with a generic function which returns generic ViewController. It's forcing me to add type constraint check in default implementation.

```
protocol RouterViewController {
    func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(_ name: Storyboard) -> T
}

extension RouterViewController {
    func getViewController<T>(_ name: Storyboard) -> T where T: UIViewController {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(storyboard: name)
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewController()
    }
}
```

The same example I can do without generics

```
    struct RouterViewController {
     static func  getViewController(_ name: Storyboard) -> UIViewController {
     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(storyboard: name)
            return storyBoard.instantiateViewController()
 }
}
```

I have a set of questions

1. If I had to do type check then I will go for factory method? How to do same with generics?
2. If I want to use generics how to check with current type in this function return like `func<SignIn>() -> T`

Comment: What is `Storyboard`?

Comment: @vadian it's a string enum for storyboards names type

Answer (score 0):

If you make small changes in your protocol declaration/extension, you will get desired functionality:

```
protocol RouterViewController {
    func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(_ viewControllerType: T.Type, _ name: Storyboard) -> T 
}

extension RouterViewController {
    func getViewController<T>(_ viewControllerType: T.Type, _ name: Storyboard) -> T where T: UIViewController {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(storyboard: name)
        let identifier = String(describing: T.self) // Let's say view controller's storyboard identifier is same as class name
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct TestStruct: RouterViewController {

}

TestStruct().getViewController(TestViewController.self, #YourStoryboardObject)
```

For more about view controllers and storyboards check: [Swift protocol extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257807/swift-protocol-extension/51607296#51607296)

Comment: you are passing a type as a parameter that is correct. But with the factory method, I can call directly. Is there any use if we use generics here..?

Comment: You can pass any UIViewController type in this generic method. It is type parameter which makes it generic. You can use this method to create any kind of UIViewController, not just TestViewController. If you want to instantiate  UIViewControllers on specific UIStoryboard object, check link i previously provided. It has more like factory approach.